# Convergence of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

You have 2 sequences (an,bn), and 2 real numbers (l and l') such that ∀ε>0,∃N ∈N:

i)  if n≥N, then |an −l|< (10^10^10^10^10)·ε

ii) if n≥N, then |bn −l'|< (1 /10^10^10^10^10)+ε

Determine if the sequences converge or not, and prove it.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think the first one converges, but the second one does not necessarily converge

Comment: I think you are right.  Do you have a more specific question that you would like answered?

Comment: I'd like to know how can I proof that the second one doesn't necessarily converge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i)

This should be pretty clear, but from the definition of the limit, let $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{10^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}}$ so the sequence does converge into $l$.

ii)

Think about what the absolute value represents in the definition of limit: even if we pick an arbitrarily large $n$, $b_n$ will be at least either $\frac{1}{10^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}}$ larger or smaller than $l'$, so the second one does not converge into $l'$, and it will not necessarily converge, since it could oscillate between two values.

Comment: How would it be the formal proof for the second sequence? I've been struggling with formalize it.

Comment: To express formally, $\nexists n \in \Bbb N : |b_n-l'|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$